# How to set event for changes in power level status of bluetooth devices in Mac OS?

Tags: objective-c, macos, bluetooth, batterylevel

I have a simple question.

Can we obtain the battery level of devices paired with mac os programmatically(with Cocoa Frameworks)? Does exists any event that provides this data?

I can get this information with NSTask and ioreg command, but i think isn't the best way.

Thank you for advance,